# Multi-step form, but redirect to another site in between?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement the same concept Ryan Bates discussed in his Railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms into my user sign up form.

Basically the 3 steps are as follows:

**Step 1.** Fill out user details

**Step 2:** Go to an external URL to complete billing details, which will redirect them back to this user sign up form when they're done.

**Step 3:** Confirm and submit data

Currently my workaround is to create the user first, then redirect to the external URL to complete payment after @user.save, but I would like to use this multistep form to prevent the user from getting saved if they don't complete payment first.

Would appreciate it if you could point me towards a direction.. thanks.

UPDATE:

My user controller:

```
  def new
        session[:user_params] ||= {}
        if params[:plan_id].present?
          @user = User.new(session[:user_params] && :plan_id => params[:plan_id])
        else
          @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
        end
        @user.current_step = session[:user_step]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  def create
      session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user]) if params[:user]
      @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
      @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
      if @user.valid?
        if params[:back_button]
          @user.previous_step
        elsif @user.last_step?
          @user.save
        elsif @user.billing_step?
          @user.next_step
          redirect_to("external.com") and return
        else
          @user.next_step
        end
        session[:user_step] = @user.current_step
      end


      if @user.new_record?
        render "new"
      else
        session[:user_step] = session[:user_params] = nil
        flash[:success] = "User saved"
        redirect_to dashboard_url
      end
    end
```

My user model:

```
  validates_presence_of :username, :first_name, :last_name, :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "initial" }

  attr_writer :current_step

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[initial billing confirmation]
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
  end

  def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end

  def billing_step?
    current_step == steps.second
  end
```

My new user view:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => {:action => :create, :plan_id => params[:plan_id] } do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= render "#{@user.current_step}_step", :f => f %>

<% end %>
```

The problem is in the user controller with the @user.billing_step?

what I need to happen after hitting the submit button is: 1.) add a step (using @user.next_step) AND 2.) redirect to an external URL.

That way, when users go back to "users/new" they're already at the final step of confirmation.

If I don't add the "and return" command at the end of the redirect, I get the "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action" error. If I do, Rails doesn't add a new step and takes me back to the billing step (step 2) of the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your user's currently input form data into a session for while they are visiting the third party service to complete their payment.

If the payment service is good, they will provide you with a hash of information (or something of the sort) with details on the user's actions (whether they paid or not) and then you can use the saved session information to complete the registration if everything is ok.

1. Let user fill out mandatory fields
2. Have a button titled "Proceed to Payment"
3. Have the button save the user information (via ajax or submit) into the session, and redirect to the payment gateway if all required fields are so far ok
4. Redirect back to the order form and and check for the session values and then the payment details that the service returned (which they usually do in the return callback url)
5. Create user if everything is OK

**Update:**

I would definitely do something like this with your code:

```
elsif @user.billing_step?
    @user.next_step
    session[:user_step] = @user.current_step
    return redirect_to("external.com")
else
```

This sets the session to the correct step and redirects, and when the user comes back they will be taken to another conditional (thus it should work?), and keeps updating the step value on the other conditions as well, since the lower session variable isn't removed.

Does this help at all? This is probably how I would do it.

Comment: That's one of the other problems; the service doesn't pass back any payment values after completing payment. You just have to specify a URL where your users get redirected to after payment is processed. For me this is my "users/new" -- the idea is, you click on the "Proceed To Payment" button which 1.) takes you to the next step, and 2.) redirects the browser to the external site. I've tried adding a `billing_step` as I mentioned in the OP, but I get the "too many redirects" error unless I put an 'and return' at the end -- which if I do, it doesn't take the user to the next step.

Comment: Okay, then you don't need to check for the payment details in-case they only redirect to the url after payment is processed, yes? Can you define it as you redirect? If so, you could create a unique ID for the to-be-registered user, and have the return url have that id in it. This could of course be done like you first described, by first saving the user, but in an "inactive" state, and then activating after a processed payment. Weird how the service doesn't include any information..

Comment: You could show us the code and it would be easier to see the logic you are currently using to do this.

Comment: All right, no prob. I didn't post it originally coz it's pretty much 98% the same as the Railscast vid, but I updated the OP regardless.

Comment: Nico....... You are a GOD. After hours and hours and hours, it finally worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH.